# Do I need to set the Java Platform (JDK) in netbeans if I am using the Pom.xml in accumulo-1.4.3?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, accumulo

I have opened/imported the accumulo "examples-simple" maven project into netbeans.  Do I need to set the Java Platform?

Properties indicate "Java SDK 7.1". I know that accumulo-1.4.3 runs on JDK 1.6.0.

My current version is java version "1.6.0_32"

I am pretty sure the answer is yes, but it never hurts to ask!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [Josh Elser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580381/elserj) on the [Apache Accumulo Mailing List](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/accumulo-dev/201402.mbox/%3C52F90DF4.3080903@gmail.com%3E), where this was cross-posted to:

> No, you don't need to.
>
> Currently, all versions of Accumulo are still guaranteed to work against
> 1.6. So, if you hypothetically contributed anything back to Accumulo,
> you would need to make sure that it runs on a 1.6 JVM. As such, it's a
> good idea to ensure that you're building with a 1.6 JVM, but not a
> requirement if you're just developing things locally for yourself.